# Webpack custom chunck location with specific https address

Tags: webpack

I'm working on an angular (current v8) project and I need to load the webpack chunks from the web with a custom js code that define the address (different versions of chunks are stored on web, and the code defines the one that needs to be used).

I found that the chunk adress is defined on jsonpScriptSrc function, and that this function is written by mainTemplate.hooks.localVars.tap (JsonpMainTemplatePlugin.js)

I need to overwrite this function (maybe with a custom plugin), or to have an other way to manage the relation chunk ID => path to chunk js file.

Do anyone has an idea??
thanks

Comment: Serge, did you ever figure this out? I'm in the same boat...

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, I found that if you modify the webpack config's `output.publicPath` option, it will use that to load in the templates.

WEBPACK 3:
Furthermore, if you need a dynamic URL instead of hardcoding it in the webpack config, you can use this DynamicPublicPath plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-public-path-webpack-plugin

WEBPACK 4:
In cases where the eventual publicPath of output files isn't known at compile time, it can be left blank and set dynamically at runtime via the **webpack_public_path** variable in the entry point file:
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#advanced